# Providing information declined offer

Tags: interviewing, software-industry

I recently started to apply for my first real job. I have received some positive offer's so far and there will probably a few more.
So I am currently in the lucky position to choose from multiple ok to very good offers.
How much information would I want to disclose to the ones I will be declining?

Should I be completely honest in how much information I disclose?
I would want to know, but I am not sure if this will hold any repercussions for me career wise in the long run.

Comment: No I don't intend to play the counter offer game

Answer (score 12):

> How much information would I want to disclose to the ones I will be
>   declining?

You only owe these companies notice that you are declining. Usually something like "Thank you for your consideration, but I have decided to decline your offer." will suffice.

If you like, you could say something on the order of "I've decided to take a position elsewhere." But since you have indicated that you don't want to solicit counter offers, you may not want to even do this much.

There's no need to disclose any more information or go into any depth.